# How to use Fingerprint reader in Ubuntu 19.10

Tags: xubuntu, asus, 19.10, fingerprint-reader, elantech

I am using Ubuntu 19.10 in Asus X510UN. Using the `lsusb` command I can't find Fingerprint Device, and it's even showing `no device found` in fprintd-enroll.
I have built-in fingerprint reader in my touchpad.

Answer (score 3):

Is your device on this list? https://fprint.freedesktop.org/supported-devices.html

I see a lot of elantech devices on the list that are fprintd-enroll supported.

Other options instead of fprint look like fingerprint-gui https://launchpad.net/~fingerprint/+archive/ubuntu/fingerprint-gui

Which supports these devices:
https://fprint.freedesktop.org/supported-devices.html

Or thinkfinger which is only think pads: 
http://www.thinkwiki.org/wiki/Integrated_Fingerprint_Reader#Software_support

I have a Lenovo L380 and am still looking for a package that supports my Synaptics fingerprint reader. I'm kind of a newbie myself so I'm still learning things but that is where I would start looking.

Comment: If you can get lsusb to list your fingerprint you may be able to add a driver request to  fdprint here: https://gitlab.freedesktop.org/libfprint/libfprint/issues?label_name=Driver+Request

Comment: My Ubuntu not Even Showing that there is fingerprint reader in my Laptop... When i use lsusb in terminal it only shows about USB and other devices but Not Fingerprint.

Comment: Broadcom fingerprint readers (e.g. used in some Dell laptops, such as Latitude 7300) don't seem to be well supported yet by fprint. I filed another request there: https://gitlab.freedesktop.org/libfprint/libfprint/issues/221

Answer (score 0):

My Ubuntu not Even Showing that there is fingerprint reader in my Laptop... When i use *lsusb* in terminal it only shows about USB and other devices but Not Fingerprint.

Answer (score 0):

As Lucas suggests, check if your device is supported.
If not, it might be under development at the fprintd project.
You kernel might not show a fingerprint device, you could try a newer kernel to see if there is a difference.

To identify your device, check for any device ID in the lsusb output that has no name behind it.

Mine shows:
Bus 001 Device 003: ID 27c6:538c Shenzhen Goodix Technology Co.,Ltd. Fingerprint Reader

It's showing the device but it does't work in fprintd-enroll either because no driver is loaded.
If your device starts with 27c6 it's likely a Goodix too.

Check with that at the project page if a driver might be under development:
https://gitlab.freedesktop.org/libfprint/libfprint/issues?scope=all&utf8=%E2%9C%93&state=opened&search=27c6
and if possible try to help out in any way.

With a bit of luck a driver may be coming from Dell, but that's not certain.
A Goodix device is apparently in the Dell Precision 5530 and they support Linux on it, but it might be the model without that ( like in previous versions).

This suggests:
https://certification.ubuntu.com/catalog/component/27c6:538c
for example for this one:
https://certification.ubuntu.com/hardware/201807-26295
that the mentioned fingerprint reader is supported by the 4.15 oem kernel.

You could try to build it from:
https://code.launchpad.net/~canonical-kernel/ubuntu/+source/linux-oem/+git/bionic/+ref/oem
or add the Dell repo to find the Dell shipped oem kernel.

I hope that helps!

Answer (score 0):

**Update 2020**

If you need an official package, Upgrade to ubuntu 20.10, Fingerprint is now supported in the latest version
[Here](https://packages.ubuntu.com/source/groovy/fprintd)